# how to disappear each element after deleting from database?

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a database app.I want to make  each item disappear from main screen after deleting it. It gets deleted after long press but becomes invisible after I exit the app and then again enter. So, how to disappear each item from main screen instantly after a long press?

Here is my code snippet to delete each item----

```
listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        FriendsDbHelper fdb = new FriendsDbHelper(MainActivity.this);
        SQLiteDatabase db = fdb.getWritableDatabase();
        db.delete(TABLE_NAME,_ID+"=?",new String[]{Long.toString(id)});

        return true;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

As you appear to be using a Cursor Adapter (*i.e. you are deleting according to the id*) then you need to

- a) re-build the Cursor and then
- b) use either the adapter's `swapCursor` or `notifyDataSetChanged` methods.

> Note! If you are not using a Cursor Adapter then you will probably
>   encounter issues if you use the **id** passed to the
>   `setOnItemLongClickListener` method, as this will not necessarily be
>   the row's id but it will be the same value as position. At first it
>   would appear to work but could the start deleting the wrong rows or
>   not delete any rows.

You code would be along the lines of :-

```
listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        FriendsDbHelper fdb = new FriendsDbHelper(MainActivity.this);
        SQLiteDatabase db = fdb.getWritableDatabase();
        db.delete(TABLE_NAME,_ID+"=?",new String[]{Long.toString(id)});
        mycursor = fdb.your_method_to_get_the_cursor(); //<<<< will need changing
        your_adapter.swapCursor(mycursor); //<<<< will need changing
        return true;
    }
});
```

#### Here's a working example :-

```
// Get the ListView according to it's id
imagelist = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.imagelist);
// Get the Cursor
images = imgdbhlpr.getAllImages();
// Instantiate the Cursor Adapter
sca = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
        images,
        new String[]{ImgDBHelper.DSCR_COL},
        new int[]{android.R.id.text1},
        0
);
//
imagelist.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        imgdbhlpr.deleteImageRow(id);
        images = imgdbhlpr.getAllImages();
        sca.swapCursor(images);
        return true;
    }
});
imagelist.setAdapter(sca);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove it from the listView. You need to call your list adapter and then call the method `notifyDataSetChanged()`